# Documentation about Secondary Indexes on Cassandra?

Tags: indexing, cassandra

I've been searching for quite a bit about secondary indexes in Cassandra. I see a lot of websites mentioning that a native secondary indexing feature is "coming in version 0.7."

It's now version 0.73. Where is the documentation about this secondary indexing feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you find [this](http://www.datastax.com/docs/0.7/data_model/secondary_indexes) useful.